# Timeout when deploying to Heroku

Tags: haskell, heroku

I'm pushing a Haskell web app with quite a few dependencies to heroku, which requires heroku to download and compile all of the dependencies.

Things consistently seem to just "stop" suddenly in the logs after a certain amount of time.  The log just stops abruptly mid-line, at a slightly diferent spot each time

After looking at `heroku logs` it seems that time between the receive and the message saying it is beginning to compile and the time between the end of compilation is always exactly **15 minutes** (plus a few seconds).  The buildpack works fine, I've used it for applications in the past.  If I remove all required packages from the dependencies, it attempts to compile my web app and it behaves exactly as it would on a local machine (it stops after complaining about a missing dependency).  I've done this with almost all of the required packages one-by-one ... but when I put a lot of them together, it fails in much the same way.

Here is an example of what the log looks like:

```
... (lots of similar lines, nothing out of the ordinary) ...

Downloading feed-0.3.9.1...                             
Downloading texmath-0.6.4...                            
Configuring resource-pool-0.2.1.1...                    
Building tagsoup-0.12.8...                              
Building resource-pool-0.2.1.1...                       
Installed hexpat-0.20.3                                 
Configuring case-insensitive-1.1...                     
Building case-insensitive-1.1...                        
Configuring void-0.6.1...                               
Installed resource-pool-0.2.1.1                         
Configuring unordered-containers-0.2.3.2...             
Installed case-insensitive-1.1                          
Downloading http-types-0.8.1...                         
Building void-0.6.1...                                  
Building unordered-containers-0.2.3.2...                
Building lifted-base-0.2.1.0...                         
Confi                                                   
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Multipack app
```

And every time, it stops on a different line and a different place in the line.  I've tried it with various buildpacks and it all seems to work the same way.

All signs seem to point to a timeout error ... the most incriminating being the fact that all failed attempts are exactly 15 minutes long ... or maybe a disk space error.  Does anyone know if there is a way to increase the timeout or speed up compilation?  Is it possible for me to pre-compile all of my binaries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to compile the binary on your machine, commit it to the Heroku-only repository and push that. [Here is a script I used](https://github.com/koterpillar/labyrinth-server/blob/master/deploy-heroku) to deploy:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

cabal configure
cabal build
cd heroku # this is my Heroku-only repository
git rm -r *
cp ../dist/build/labyrinth-server/labyrinth-server .
cp -r ../public/ . # this is the static files directory
echo "web: ./labyrinth-server" > Procfile
touch requirements.txt # pretend to be a Python app, otherwise Heroku doesn't know what to do
git add *
git commit -m "New version."
git push
cd - >/dev/null
```

Note: I switched to OpenShift later, and the [OpenShift deploy script](https://github.com/koterpillar/labyrinth-server/blob/master/deploy-rhc) has a few enhancements.

Another note: you should make sure you are building on a machine with compatible architecture and link against an existing `libc` version. You can check all that yourself if you SSH onto the server manually (`rhc ssh` or `heroku run bash`). For the current OpenShift, a Debian Wheezy x64 machine produces compatible binaries.

Comment: How can I be sure that my machine has the same architecure as whatever Heroku is running and can run compatible binaries?

Comment: Was hoping there would be a way to extend the timeout, but i think as of this moment in time this is really the only solution.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the information about Debian! Just what I needed

Answer (score 1):

Wrote a **[write-up addressing this problem and full step-by-step instructions](http://blog.jle.im/entry/deploying-medium-to-large-haskell-apps-to-heroku)** for such a pre-compiled deploy.